# Commenting out view on Main story board

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there a way I could comment a view on my Main story board so that I can uncomment and use later?
I tried commenting out the view by opening the Main story board source code (xml) and commenting the view manually but I always find that xcode force remove the uncommented lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can uncheck `Installed` in Attributes Inspector, so it will behave as the UI element does not exist for rendering, you can enable/delete it later when you need.

[image]